# Importing external C++ library with no .dll and .lib

Tags: c++, cmake

Before I start I'd like to say that I've searched for the past couple of hours online, to no avail.

I'm trying to use [CFugue](http://cfugue.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html#features) as a library to manipulate music in my project, and I'm trying to pipeline it into VS 2017 at the moment. Going through the stuff I downloaded, I realized that there's neither a .dll file nor a .lib file.

Am I supposed to compile those, and if so, how? If not, is this actually a library? How do I go about setting this up to use?

(I'm probably missing somethign really dumb, but I don't know what it is.)

Comment: Did you follow the instructions for building the project?  Try reading the README files.

Comment: Instructions are here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/cfugue/files/CFugue/  1. Download the latest source of CFugue from https://sourceforge.net/projects/cfugue/files/CFugue/  2. Build CFugue using CMake 3. After build is done, you can run 'bin/testCFugueLib'

Comment: CFuge uses CMake with `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: Yeah. there was a `cmakelists.txt` given so I ran the whole thing through cmake. It built, but the whole bin folder is empty.

Comment: I built and found `sampleapp.cpp` and tried to run `testcfuguelib` and I get an error saying something in Debug doesn't exist?

Comment: You have to be specific with the error messages.

Comment: We can guess at how you build a Debug version using CMake. But guessing is not a productive approach. drescherjm is right, we need more information.